# Why is my Drupal main menu not showing up?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7

I am using an Omega subtheme. I am trying to incorporate bootstrap CSS for my responsiveness. For some reason I can't figure out, the menu items are not showing up.

HTML

```
<div class="menu_wrapper">
```

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li>

            <a href="#">

            <?php $menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
                                print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $menu));?>

                        </a>

                </li>

      </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-wrapper {
    background-color: #c32523;
    opacity: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.navbar {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Any errors coming out of it? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: If this is all the code you provide, it will be very difficult for us to help. There is a lot that is missing and subsequently, a lot that can go wrong. Please provide a more detailed example and the errors that you get.